# Declare 3d array with dynamic 3th dimension in C#

Tags: c#

I need to declare 3d array variable but can't.

```
int[][][]  ary = new int[5][2][];
ary[0,0] = new int[20];
ary[0,1] = new int[3];
```

Could you please help me!

Thanks in advance
Hamid

Comment: You may want to read this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/17/arrays-of-arrays.aspx) (from Eric Lippert's Blog) very carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int[,][] ary = new int[5,2][];
```

declares a 2D array of `int[]` objects and initializes it. Use

```
ary[0, 0] = new int[10];
ary[0, 0][0] = 42;
```

to access elements.

Note that in C#, multidimensional arrays are different from arrays of arrays. That is, `int[][][]` is a single dimensional array of single dimensional arrays of single dimensional arrays of integers while `int[,,]` is a three dimensional array of integers.